# C# creating function that automatically adds ID to List items

Tags: c#, variables

I'm creating function that adds items to function from console. How can I add variable that will increase from zero every time function is called and finished? I tried adding variable in class function is in but doesn't seem to work :

```
public class example 
{
.............
int currid = 0;
public void addnew(){
......
......
currid++;
}
//main
}
```

Is there any way to initialize such a int variable? I get ID to my items from currid, because I want them to be specific for every item.

Comment: Can you explain a little more specifically please?

Comment: Declare the variable as static.

Comment: how you  are calling addNew() method  show more code please

Comment: `static int currid = 0;` will do.

Comment: I use ID = currid in function addnew, I need currid to be +1 everytime I run function addnew. so let's say Item2.ID will be Item2.ID +1 (take a look at it as if it was math, not syntax because I'm not sure if it's correct)

Comment: try  static variable  it will solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if My guess is correct try to  use a static variable

```
public class example 
{
.............
public static int  currid = 0;
public void addnew(){
......
......
currid++;
}
//main
}
```